# how to pass varchar string to stored procedure where in condition?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how to pass varchar string to stored procedure where in condition?
here, where in condition not work how to solve this problem?

```
CALL searchStudentByName("%AAP%","'1','2','3'");
```

MYSQL Stored Procedures:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `studentsdb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `searchStudentByName`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchStudentByName`(IN `search_key` VARCHAR(40),IN `student_ids` VARCHAR(350))
BEGIN  
    SELECT students.StudentId,students.StudentName FROM students WHERE students.Status='A' AND students.StudentName LIKE search_key AND students.StudentId NOT IN(student_ids) LIMIT 5;   
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to prepare a statement to use a list of values like that. Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchStudentByName`(IN `search_key` VARCHAR(40),IN `student_ids` VARCHAR(350))
BEGIN  
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT students.StudentId,students.StudentName FROM students WHERE students.Status='A' AND students.StudentName LIKE '", search_key, "' AND students.StudentId NOT IN(", student_ids, ") LIMIT 5");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you are missing like where condition. after edit (SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT students.StudentId,students.StudentName FROM students WHERE students.Status='A' AND students.StudentName LIKE '",search_key,"' AND students.StudentId NOT IN(", student_ids, ") LIMIT 5");
    ) this work correct

Comment: @VIJAY I looked back and your edit was rejected by other reviewers (I don't think they saw the change because it was off to the right of the screen) but I have fixed the code myself. Thanks for pointing out the error.